# I cannot insert records into Database using HTML Form and PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, apache, easyphp

No records show up in my MyPHP Database when I run these scripts.

I am running:
APACHE  2.4.7 
MYSQL  5.6.15 
PHP  5.5.8

First the HTML Code...

```
<html>

<center>
  <font face="Helvetica">

<u><b>Matthew Gieger's Guestbook</b></u>

<form action="link.php" method="post"/>
<p>Name: </p>
<input type="text" name="Name" required/>
<p>Email: </p>
<input type="email" name="Email" required />
<p>Message: </p>
<p><textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="Message"> </textarea></p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>
</center>
</html>
```

And the PHP Script. This is where I think the problem is...

```
 <?php

$username='root';
$password='';
$database='guestbook';

$name= $_POST['Name'];
$email= $_POST['Email'];
$message= $_POST['Message'];

new mysqli('localhost',$username,$password,$database) or die("could not connect to localhost");

echo"connected";

mysqli:"insert into contacts (Name,Email,Message,Timestamp) values ($name,$email,$message,date())";

?>
```

I get no error when I run the code. I just get the expected 
"connected"

Comment: Try to debug it through if condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a `mysqli` object defined anywhere. And you're not using `mysqli_query()` anywhere.

[Here are the docs to `mysqli`.](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Try something like this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', $username, $password, $database);

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `contacts`(`Name`, `Email`, `Message`, `Timestamp`) VALUES ('". $name ."', '". $email ."', '". $message ."', '". $timestamp ."')");
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much! Sorry i can't vote up.. i don't have enough reputation.

Comment: @MattG Look at Schlaus' answer too, to prevent a security issue (sql injection).

Comment: I'm still having an issue adding a second record to the database. It seems as tho it won't allow any more than 1 record. Have any ideas?

Comment: @MattG Well, have you set an `id` for example? It could be you keep trying to insert a record with `id = 1`, but since that record already exists now, you'll need to make the next record's `id` 2. You can have `MySQL` do this automagically for you by using the `AI - Auto Increment` option on a field. Without any errors or more specifics I can't really make any other guesses though ;)

Comment: Oh Ok thats probably it. I couldn't find the option to auto increment when i set up the fields a few days ago. I'll take a look at the documentation, and im sure that will fix it! Thanks Again

Comment: @MattG If you're using phpmyadmin with mysql, you can edit the `id` field very easily. Look for a checkbox that says `AI` and check it. You may need to get rid of your data first though.

Answer (score 1):

You're not instantiating the mysqli class properly. You need to save the object instance into a variable:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost',$username,$password,$database);

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

There's also a serious security issue in your code, since you're not escaping your input variables. Best solution would be to look into PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php and parameter binding.

If you really want to do this with mysqli, you should first use [mysqli_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) on all your input variables:

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['Name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['Email']);
$message = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['Message']);
```

And then run your query properly:

```
$mysqli->query("insert into contacts (Name,Email,Message,Timestamp) values ('$name','$email','$message',".date().")";
```

If you don't escape the user input's, it will be really easy to hack your database with a simple [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: +1 for the injection vulnerability, forgot to mention that myself.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! This is just for a class project, but thats definitely good to know!

Answer (score 0):

most likely a formatting issue, try it like this:

```
<?php 
$username='root';
$password='';
$database='guestbook';

$name= $_POST['Name'];
$email= $_POST['Email'];
$message= $_POST['Message'];
$db = new mysqli('localhost',$username,$password,$database) or die("could not connect to localhost");

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}
$currentDate=date();
$sql = "insert into contacts (Name,Email,Message,Timestamp) values ($name,$email,$message,$currentDate)";

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}

?>
```

Comment: It returned a few errors, but you were right that i needed the mysqli. I guess i need to brush up!